# How to translate custom plugin by creating .po and .mo file

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

Basically my requirement is to translate my custom plugin in dutch language for WPML. So when I change the language from english to dutch, It has to automatically change all the text of my plugin in admin panel. I am creating .po file from poedit software. It generates two files .po and .mo file. I put them in the plugin folder;

```
../wp-content/plugins/cleaner/languages/nl_NL.po
../wp-content/plugins/cleaner/languages/nl_NL.mo
```

Now I put this code in root file of the plugin.

```
add_action('init', 'cleaner_load_textdomain');

function cleaner_load_textdomain() {

    load_plugin_textdomain(
          'cleaner'
        , false
        , basename(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/languages'
    );

}
```

But it is not doing anything. Any suggetions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_plugin_textdomain/: _"The .mo file should be named based on the text domain with a dash, and then the locale exactly."_

Comment: hello @04FS, I renamed both files as **cleaner-nl_NL.po** and **cleaner-nl_NL.mo**, But it still not appearing for WPML.